# Predicting the missing data out of three values in each of the two vectors

Tags: time-series, arima, prediction, population, interpolation

I have 2 vectors of rural and urban populations of the same country. (years from 1975 to 2020) with only three values (1980, 1990 and 2001 years) in each. And I need to predict the missing data. My first approach was to interpolate the data in between the known years(using na.approx in R) and then use make an ARIMA model, however I am not sure if its a good idea, since the graphics look kind of awkward.
 Also the values are "waving", for example, urban population -  4000 in 1980,  3800 in 1990 and 3950 in 2001. Any ideas on how to make a better prediction would be really helpful.

Comment: Are you saying, in effect, that you have just *six* data values? (Rural populations in 1980, 1990, and 2001 and urban populations in 1980, 1990, and 2001.) If not, please describe your data more fully.

Comment: Yes, sorry for my English though.